# Subsequence question

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $x_{2n}$ and $x_{3n}$ converge to the same limit must $x_n$ converge?

I think no because you can construct a subsequence that converges to something else using $x_5,x_7,..$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. An explicit example would be

$$x_n=\begin{cases}0 &\text{for } 2 \mid n \text{ or } 3 \mid n\\1 &\text{for } 2 \nmid n \text{ and } 3 \nmid n\end{cases}$$

where $|$ denotes divisibility and $\nmid $ denotes nondivisibility, or equivalently:

$$x_n=\begin{cases}1 &\text{for } n \equiv\pm1 \pmod 6\\0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$